# problem passing data to main page in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I wanna show a list of posts in main page and here is what I did:

Rout file:

```
Route::get('/', [ 
       'uses' => 'WelcomeController@index',
       'as' => 'welcome'
    ]);
```

WellcomeController:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Models\Post;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class WelcomeController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        $posts = Post::all();
        return view('welcome')->with('posts', $posts);
    }
```

welcome.blade.php :

```
@extends ('layout')

@section('content')

    <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-10 mx-auto">
            @foreach ($posts as $post)
            <div class="post-preview">
                <a href="">
                    <h2 class="post-title">
                        {{$post->title}}
                    </h2>
                    <h3 class="post-subtitle">
                        {{$post->description}}
                    </h3>
                </a>
                <p class="post-meta">Posted by
                    <a href="#">Start Bootstrap</a>
                    on September 24, 2019</p>
            </div>
            <hr>
        @endforeach
            <!-- Pager -->
```

but it shows this error when loading the page:

```
>>ErrorException
>>Undefined variable: posts (View: C:\Users\z.mofidi\test1\resources\views\welcome.blade.php)
>>http://127.0.0.1:8000/
>>$posts is undefined
```

I'm wondering what I missed. Thanks for your suggestions in advance.

Comment: Try running `php artisan view:clear` from the terminal

Comment: @Donkarnash thanks for your answer. i did it  but still shows same error exception .

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 public function index(){
     $data['posts'] = Post::all();
     return view('welcome', $data);
 }
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. I did it but nothing have changed and it shows same error exception again.

Comment: Try running `php artisan cache:clear` in your terminal